# passing gradient to sqp

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm trying to provide a gradient when using **sqp** in Octave but I keep getting a "syntax error".  What is the problem?  Thank you.

```
sqp(0.5*ones(10,1), 
    { @(w) phi(w, g_beta, g_eta, sigmas, estXtpv),
      @(w) gradphi(w, g_beta, g_eta, sigmas, estXtpv) },
    @(w) 0,
    @(w) 0);
```

The error I get is

```
parse error near line 193 of file ...

  syntax error

>>>  { @(w) phi(w, g_beta, g_eta, sigmas, estXtpv),
           ^
```

If I remove {} and remove the gradient (gradphi), then the syntax error disappears.

I'm using Octave 3.2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug. Try without space i.e. `{@(w)phi(w, ...` .

Comment: Glad to hear that it solved your problem. Care to send a bug report to http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?group=octave. Thanks